# Laravel simple creating new row in table

Tags: laravel-4

Hello im new in Laravel and im not able to add data to database from form. I have simple one view with only one form. Controller have 2 actions (for view form and for creating db rows).

**app/routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'FrontendController@index');
Route::post('/', 'FrontendController@submit');
```

**app/views/index.blade.php**

```
{{Form::open(array('action'=>'FrontendController@submit','class'=>'form-horizontal','role'=>'form'))}}
{{Form::text('nazev_firmy',Input::old('nazev_firmy'), array('class'=>'form-control'))}}
{{Form::submit('Send', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary submit'))}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

**/app/controllers/FrontendController.php**

```
class FrontendController extends BaseController {
        public function index()
    {
        return View::make('index');
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        $inzerat = new Inzerat;

        $inzerat->nazev_firmy = Input::post('nazev_firmy');
        $inzerat->save();

        return View::make('index');
    }

}
```

**app/models/Inzerat.php**

```
<?php

class Inzerat extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'inzeraty'; 
    public $timestamps = false; 

}
```

**ERROR AFTER CLICK ON SUBMIT BUTTON**

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::post()
```

Im using Laravel 4.0

What i have done wrong here ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In laravel, you use ::get() to retrieve all input from the request. You just need to change

```
$inzerat->nazev_firmy = Input::post('nazev_firmy');
```

To:

```
$inzerat->nazev_firmy = Input::get('nazev_firmy');
```